# Positive ordered pair of $(10x)^2+(5y)^2<1,000,000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I find the number of ordered pair $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ where $(10x)^2+(5y)^2<1,000,000$?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see why $x<100$ and $y<200$?

Comment: I guess because if x=100 or y=200 the sum wouldn't be less than a million?

Comment: Oh let me try answering this myself

Comment: is my answer correct?

Comment: Do you see why you’re asking for the number of “lattice points” inside the ellipse $4x^2+y^2=(200)^2$?

Answer (score 4):

To get an approximate answer, note that the ellipse with axes [-100,100] in $x$ and $[-200,200]$ in $y$ has area $20000\pi\approx 62864$.  This is the approximate number of lattice points in the ellipse.  $600$ are on the axes, and a quarter of what is left is in the first quadrant, so there are approximately $\frac 14 \cdot 62264=15566$ solutions

Comment: +1 I was just typing part of your answer as a comment.  Seeing the connection between the area of the region and the number of lattice points inside is good connection to make.

Comment: @JavaMan: and it is *almost* within $0.1\%$

Answer (score 1):

$(10x)^2+(5y)^2<1000000$

$(5y)^2<1000000-(10x)^2$

$5y<\sqrt{1000000-(10x)^2}$

$y<2\sqrt{10000-x^2}$

Let $x=1$ for an example $y<199.9899997$ or one can say that there are $199$ possible ordered pairs $(x,y)$ when $x=1$.

Now you need to workout $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{99}\left\lfloor2\sqrt{10000-x^2}\right\rfloor$.

With some help from Wolfram, we get $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{99}\left\lfloor2\sqrt{10000-x^2}\right\rfloor=15552$ .

Comment: Why the factor $2$ and why does the sum start at $0$?  OP asked for solutions in the positive integers.

Comment: The sum should've started from $1$. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm editing the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force solution using *Mathematica*:

```
n = 0; For[x = 1, x < 100, x++, 
 For[y = 1, (10 x)^2 + (5 y)^2 < 1000000, y++, n++]]; n
```

returns

```
15548
```

Comment: Haha, I just realized that myself - I think I'm too used to problems where the actual solutions are desired that that's what I default to. I've edited now.

Answer (score -2):

I'm trying to answer this myself, check my work if I'm correct:

Since x can't be more than or equal to 100, and for y can't be more than or equal to 200, so there's 99*199 combinations possible?

Comment: No, there are at most $99\cdot 199$ possible combinations, but for example $x=99,y=199$ is not acceptable.

Comment: Oh but how do I eliminate the one that doesn't satisfy the condition?  So I have to do it by brute force?

Comment: Some other answers give you good approximate solutions, but if you want the exact result I don't know of other methods than bruteforce (but I'm not a number theorist).